# Building custom card view programmatically

Tags: android, layout, view, textview, android-cardview

I've got problem with creating custom view programmatically.

I wrote something like:

```
public class TimerCardView extends CardView {
    private LinearLayout horizontalContentLayout;
    private TextView timeTextView;


    public TimerCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        horizontalContentLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams horizontalContentXLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        horizontalContentXLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        horizontalContentLayout.setLayoutParams(horizontalContentXLayoutParams);

        this.addView(horizontalContentLayout);

        timeTextView = new TextView(context);
        timeTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#A3A3A3"));
        timeTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 40);
        timeTextView.setText("0:00:00");

        this.horizontalContentLayout.addView(timeTextView);
    }
}
```

and in xml I added:

```
<com.example.paciu.belmondo.ViewsExtends.TimerCardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">
</com.example.paciu.belmondo.ViewsExtends.TimerCardView>
```

And the problem is that my text view isn't centered on the screen in the layout. It still stays to the left. But when I added firstly to the xml the same (but the whole in xml):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:text="sdasdasd"
                android:textColor="#AAAAAA" />

        </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I tried it also, but it stays the same. Why then in the second xml without that is OK? In the second xml the whole layout is centered...Why then my class code centering does not work ?

Comment: `horizontalContentLayout.addView(timeTextView, horizontalContentXLayoutParams)` should do it

Comment: Still does not work.

Comment: try with `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` for  the width instead of `WRAP_CONTENT`

Comment: with both MATCH_PARENT in horizontalLayout and timeTextView it works. But what if I wanted add second textview to the layout? I don't see why is that?

Comment: it depends on the orientation of your LinearLayout. I assume it is vertical, but since it is never set it is horizontal by default. Is that what you want ?

Comment: not exactly. I can set surely orientation of layout to horizontal by: `horizontalContentLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);`
but it also does not work with wrap content...

Answer (score 0):

CardView extends the FrameLayout class. The `layout_gravity` attribute lands on the `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`, not on the view **horizontalContentLayout**. For setting gravity like in your XML use something like:

```
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER);
    this.addView(horizontalContentLayout,params);
```